# Unable to save values to Postgres using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The error is when I am saving the values to the model.
The contract class is:

```
class StateVariables(db.Model):
    __tablename__='statevariables'
    id=db.Column(db.String, unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name=db.Column(db.String)
    address=db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('contract.address'), unique=True, nullable=False)
    value=db.Column(db.String)
    type=db.Column(db.String)
    
    def __init__(self,address,id,name,type,value):
        id=self.id
        name=self.name
        address=self.address
        value=self.value
        type=self.type






d=Analysis(keys="",function="",name=dataObj[3],type="Extraction",place="",mapping_id="id")
    f=1
    
for h in dataObj[0]:
    gor=h
    
    g = ac+str(f)
    
    if (gor[0].find("key")==-1):
        a=StateVariables(address=ac,id=g,name=gor[0],type=gor[1],value=gor[2])
        db.session.add(a)
        db.session.commit()
        t=StateValues(value=gor[2],Timestamp=dt_string,id=g)
        db.session.add(t)
        db.session.commit()
```

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null).

> [SQL: INSERT INTO statevariables (name, address, value, type) VALUES
> (%(name)s, %(address)s, %(value)s, %(type)s)] [parameters: {'name':
> None, 'address': None, 'value': None, 'type': None}] (Background on
> this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
> 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jul/2021 12:06:00] "POST /extractionSave HTTP/1.1" 500

All the values are in string.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyVB5.png)

Comment: Don't post code and error as image, instead insert code blocks with the raw text

Comment: Clearly all the values that you are passing to the `__init__` method are `None`, so the `NOT NULL` constraint on the `id` column is triggered.   If you don't try to set `id` in the `__init__` method then it will be set automatically because you have `primary_key=True`

Comment: @snakecharmerb but I want to set the primary key with the value passed.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice you were using a string column.  But the first part of the comment still applies: you are passing `None` as the `id` value.

Comment: @snakecharmerb corrected still the same error.

Comment: `address` is also not allowed to be `NULL` / `None`.  If you are passing suitable values for both of these columns then you should be able to save.  Can you share some data that reproduce the error?